# If quotient by a closed normal subgroup is discrete

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, normal-subgroups

Suppose that $T$ is a topological group and $K$ is a closed normal subgroup. Is $T/K$ a discrete space?

I think it is, since $tK$ for all $t\in T$ is closed, i.e. every singleton $\{tK\}$ is closed. But why most books state that such a quotient is Hausdorff if it is true that it is discrete?

Comment: Every singleton is closed (as opposed to open) doesn't mean that it's discrete...

Comment: @YuiToCheng yes exactly thanks

Comment: The quotient by an *open* subgroup would be discrete.

Comment: @Alexey Yes thanks I thought closed sets in this case would behave like open sets

Comment: They would if the subgroup was of finite index :).

Comment: @Alexey yes once I knew the answer is no I realized that the union of closed sets is not closed necessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}/{\mathbb{Z}}$ is just the circle group $S^1$, far from discrete.

The fact that all cosets are closed (which is true) just says that the quotient is $T_1$ and thus Tychonoff (as a topological group as well). In my example $K$ is discrete and the resulting quotient is compact Hausdorff and metrisable.

Comment: Yes thanks, I thought each singleton being closed implied discreteness like open sets

Comment: @User12239 no singletons open means discrete, so if we modded out by an open normal subgroup $K$ (which is then automatically closed as well) then $T/{K}$ would be discrete.